# Can I have more than 5 notifications of an event in Google Calendar?

Tags: google-calendar, notifications

Is there a way to add more than 5 notifications to an event in Google Calendar? There are some events that I like to have multiple reminders in the days preceding it as well as a bunch more the day of the event.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be any way to get more than 5 notifications for one event in google calendar.

One workaround that may be useful is to create two (or more) events starting at the same time as the event you (really) want to remember, and then add five reminders to each of those.

Comment: Very clever workaround.